# Using Git tag as checked out version for Production

Tags: git, bamboo, git-flow

So, this is actually part of a much bigger planning project I'm working on... Not sure background would help with this question, though.

I'm somewhat new to Git - been using it for about 5 months - I also have experience with SVN. My question is: would it be bad practice to use a Git tag for production?

For example, let's say production lives in /var/www/live ... I'm considering the following as part of a deployment plan:

- release branch merges into master
- master is pulled on a preview server
- once approved, a process fires to make a tag of that version, go to the production location, and check out that tag

Worth keeping in mind that I'm also learning how we might apply Git Flow, and we're using Bamboo for deployment (which I've never used), so it's all fairly messy right now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you're on the right track, and this is a perfectly valid usecase for a Tag on `git`.

Since you mentioned Gitflow, it would mature your envisioned branching model a bit further, separating the development branches from release and master branches, having a quick way to branch out and merge back hotfixes and using tags for every merge on master (which would be always a new prod version). Bamboo plan can tag these commits automatically, btw.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good practice. I think this is the purpose for which tags were envisioned. That way there's never any confusion about which code is at the tip of the ephemeral "production" branch. There's a cemented distinction about the state of the repository and its files.

Even Github ties tags to [releases](https://github.com/blog/1547-release-your-software).